# making a collapsible sidebar icon displaying with custom react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const useSideBar = () => {
const [sideBarSize, setSideBarSize] = useState("min");
const handleToggle = () => {
    if (window.innerWidth > 50) {
        setSideBarSize("max");
    } else window.innerWidth < 50;
    setSideBarSize("min");
};

return (
    <div className={sideBarSize ? "bo-sidebar active" : "bo-sidebar"}>
        <Sidebar />
        <button
            class="btn btn-primary"
            id="menu-toggle"
            onClick={() => handleToggle()}
        >
        Toggle Menu
      </button>
    </div>
)
}

export default useSideBar;
```

I'm tasked with creating a collapsible sidebar base on the screen size thereby displaying the sidebar icons alone, been that the normal width is 250px. So far this is what I've achieved but I'm not still getting it. And I still need to call the this component in the Sidebar Component

Please someone should help out

Comment: Pleas share codesandbox see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Okay @DennisVash. I needed a collapsible sidebar component, that when clicked on it collapses inside displaying only the icon, and if clicked on again it collapses out thereby returning to its default width

Comment: @lakaJS like this one.? https://codepen.io/bsurnida/pen/byVMBd

Comment: Yes @AkshayPagare but with custom react hooks and not with bootstrap